# ¿Existe alguna alternativa al modulo de webbrowser?

Tags: python, modulos

Qué tal buen día, mi pregunta es ¿Existe alguna alternativa del módulo webbrowser de python? necesito saber si existe para poder manejar distintas tabs (pestañas) (cerrar, abrir, evitar que abran, etc.) Tengo una app que abre una ventana del navegador, y mediante un `for` hace varias tareas, pero este bucle hace que me abra varias tabs, he buscado en la documentación y no hay manera de controlar las tabs. Por eso mi duda, existe algún módulo parecido.

Comment: No se entiende bien qué buscas, pero quizás [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) pueda ser lo que necesitas.

Comment: el for no es un bucle infinito, lo que tienes que hacer es poner la cantidad de veces que se pueda abrir las ventanas del navegador. por ejemplo si quieres que solo habra 12 ventanas del navegador escribe un codigo con el bucle for para limitar las pestañas depsués de eso no se como hacerlo.